# Interpretation of power analysis

Tags: sampling, chi-squared-test, sample-size, statistical-power, count-data

I have done power analysis for a chi-squared test to calculate the sample size I would need for power of 80%. I have these questions:

Have I calculated the effect size (w) correctly - 0.81?

Is a sample size of 15 required?

Would a sample size of 15 also be ok for a Fisher's exact test?

```r
library(pwr)

c(22L, 7L, 1L, 0L, 11L, 19L) -> counts

counts/sum(counts) -> prob

matrix(prob, ncol = 2) -> matrix

ES.w2(matrix) -> es

pwr.chisq.test(w=es, df=2, power=0.80, sig.level=0.05)
    
  # Chi squared power calculation 
    
  # w = 0.81
  # N = 15
  # df = 2
  # sig.level = 0.05
  # power = 0.8
   
  # NOTE: N is the number of observations
```

Comment: Whether you did the power calculation for the Chi-squared test correctly depends quite a bit on whether you put the 2x3 matrix together as intended. Note the difference between `matrix(prob, ncol = 2, byrow = FALSE)` and `matrix(prob, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)`. The argument `byrow` is False by default.

Comment: Yes matrix is correct

Comment: Then the power calculation is correct. As always, the accuracy of the calculation depends on the quality of the assumptions: how reasonable are these counts as an estimate of the alternative hypothesis? Most of the power comes from the pairs (22, 0) and (1, 19). These are very big differences and easy to detect. That's why the sample size need is 15.

Comment: What about the effect size of 0.81 - is that calculated correctly?

Comment: The effect size of 0.81 is a (deterministic) function of the probabilities. So numerically it's correct. Whether this power calculation is any good for choosing sample size depends entirely on whether you have an accurate estimate of the probabilities. So it all depends on how realistic the `counts` are. `pwr` cannot tell you that.

Comment: In other words, the difference between the observed probabilities from the pairs (22,0) and (1,19) is so big, you need only 15 samples to detect a difference that big (or more extreme). If the true probabilities are not quite as extreme as these ones, then the study you are planning might be under-powered to detect a smaller difference.